# Why asterisk (*) is used after int? ptr = (int*) malloc (100 * sizeof(int));

Tags: c++, c

`malloc()` allocates memory and returns its **starting address**, so if we want to assign that **address** to an `int` pointer, shouldnt we type-cast with only `(int)` instead of `(int*)`? It is just returning an address of `void` type, and its an address, so it will definitely be assigned to a pointer, so why do we add `*` after `int` in type-casting?

Comment: You should not cast a pointer value to `int`.

Comment: " so why we add * after int in typecasting ??" because * is the thing what makes type a pointer.

Comment: @ Slava 1 but we are providing an address to a pointer so then what is there a need of adding a * infront of data type. Adding * infront of data type will cast the address as a pointer and it will become a pointer assigned to a pointer variable. can you please elaborate its really very confusing

Comment: I can't tell if you're asking about language semantics or not. Some code in your question instead of injected in the middle of the title would be helpful. _but we are providing an address to a pointer_ .. I see no addresses to pointers in your title code.

Comment: @Hunt What language are you using?  `C` requires no cast when calling `malloc`.  This is where C and C++ differ, and you should tag the language you're using.

Answer (score 1):

> so why we add * after int in typecasting?

Because the `*` is part of the type. `int*` is a pointer while `int` is an integer. They're two different things.

Also, if you take a look at the documentation for `malloc` ([for example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc)) you'll find that it returns a `void*`. There too the `*` is being used to declare that it's a pointer. So casting from one type of pointer to another type of pointer, uses the `*` in the type.

Comment: thanks for the answer i understood everything. One last thing i want to ask and it has kept me very confused. if we are getting an address we will type cast it depending upon the data we want to store and that address is assigned to a pointer variable lets say (int *ptr = (int)(0XDEADBEEF)) . this fabricated address is not gonna get stored in ptr unless we type cast the address as (int*) . This is confusing me alot because we are providing an address to pointer variable so why should we typecast an address as pointer?

Comment: @Hunt `0xDEADBEEF` is an integer literal, it is not a pointer. `ptr` is a pointer to an integer, it is not an integer. You need a type-cast to convert from one type to another. Also, FYI, please wrap code snippets in backticks (``) to avoid formatting issues. [Read the markdown documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: @Remy Lebeau 0xdeadbeef is an address of memory location which will hold the an integer value. and i am assigning this address to an int pointer ( int *ptr = (int*)(0xdeadbeef). the thing that i am not getting is why when i typecast an address i have to add * like above . Because when we typecast a variable we dont add *

Comment: @Hunt `0xDEADBEEF` *itself* is an integer, not an address. But it *represents* an invalid address for debugging purposes. It is not meant to point at a valid memory block that can hold *anything*. To actually *store* that integer value *as an address* into a pointer variable, you must typecast the Integer to a pointer type. `int*` is a pointer type. `int` is not.

Answer (score 0):

The `(int *)` before `malloc` is a *cast* - it means "treat the return value of `malloc` as a *pointer to `int`*".

Since the 1989 standard, that cast is not necessary in C<sup>1</sup> - `malloc` returns a value of type "pointer to `void`" (`void *`), which can be assigned to objects of different pointer types, and most of us will recommend not using it (it adds clutter for little benefit and increases the maintenance burden).

Before the 1989 standard `malloc` returned "pointer to `char`" (`char *`), which cannot be assigned to other pointer types without the cast.  Anyone who wrote C in the early ‘80s (or wrote a reference manual at the time) was accustomed to using the cast, and the practice still persists.

---

1. This is *not* the case in C++ - C++ does not allow implicit conversion from `void *` to other pointer types, so a cast is required.  However, if you're writing C++, you shouldn't be using `malloc` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure everyone has their favorite answer to this question, but I think it helps if you realize that basically *everything* on a CPU is just a pointer to a memory address. The CPU itself has a very small set of 'registers' it can work with, and the way you get any data structure at all is to follow a memory pointer. The type only has meaning to you the *programmer* and the *computer language* enforced by the compiler, and is just a way to organize and keep track of things. It doesn't mean anything at all to the CPU.

In C/C++, the design of the language tries to make this reality (unavoidable in assembly language and machine code) easily accessible. That's one reason why it has been such a popular "systems language" for so long.

All `malloc` does is set aside a chunk of system memory that is at least as large as the size in bytes you asked for, and returns the start address of that memory. It does not have any idea at all what *type* it is. It could be space you use for a structure in heap memory. It could be an array of ints, an array of floats, or an array of some structure. The 'cast' after calling malloc is there to let the *language* and the *programmer* remember what type you intend to use that memory for.

```
int* ptr = (int *)malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
```

You know it's a pointer to enough memory for 100 ints, so you can use it as `ptr[x]` where x is 0..99 safely. You could use it as `*ptr`, and you can use it as `*ptr++` as long as you only do so 100 times. In this case, the *computer language* itself doesn't have any more information about the `ptr` other than it's a pointer-to-an-int.

> While you can use this syntax in C++ as well, there's a slightly *more* type-safe way to do it which avoids some of the clutter, but in the end it does exactly the same thing: `int* ptr = new int[100];`.

> A C++ programmer would recommend you use stuff like `std::array<int, 100>`, `std::vector<int>`, and/or `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` which is more 'organized' and 'type-safe', but in the end the CPU is still doing the same thing with memory addresses.

> The original *The C Programming Language* by Brian Kernighan & Dennis Ritchie is a great way to get started on any version of C or C++, or frankly any of the many other languages that all borrow heavily from the C language design.

Comment: thanks i understood the only thing confusing me now is * you added to type cast the address returned by malloc and it has kept me very confused. lets say if we are getting an address we will type cast it depending upon the data we want to store and that address is assigned to a pointer variable lets say (int ptr = (int)(0XDEADBEEF)) . this fabricated address is not gonna get stored in ptr unless we type cast the address as (int) . This is confusing me alot because we are providing an address to pointer variable so why should we typecast an address as pointer?

Comment: If you use ``*ptr = 0xdeadbeef;``, then the memory address pointed to by ``ptr`` will contain the int value ``0xdeadbeef``.  If you use ``*((int*)0xdeadbeef) = `` for any value, then it will throw an invalid memory access exception on most systems because the 'fabricated address' doesn't point to anything valid for the current process (i.e. either a crash or you just overwrote some random thing in your memory space)

Comment: @ Chuck Walbourn my main question is i just couldnt wrap my head around why we are using *  during typecasting an "address" . because the address is being assigned to a pointer .here ptr= ((int*)0xdeadbeef) i just want to know the logic why we use (int*) instead of int

Comment: ``(int)`` means "cast the type to an integer".  ``(int*)`` means "cast the type to a pointer-to-an-integer". The first is a number. The second is a memory address you can dereference.

Answer (score 0):

Memory check is required when this code is implemented in the embedded process or controller

```
int *ptr;  // pointer declaration

ptr = malloc(100 * sizeof(int));  // create an array of 100 int pointers

if(prt == null)
{
  printf("memory failed \n");  //can't process
  return ;
}

for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)  // fill it like a standard array
    ptr[i] = i;

for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)  // process it
    printf("%d\n", ptr[i]);     

free(ptr);  // clean up
```